# How to bring IRunnableWithProgress always to front layer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the **IRunnableWithProgress** Dialog in eclipse in order to show the current progress state. Whenever i have another dialog open, like the propertypages, the progressdialog doesn't appear in the foreground. Is there a way to force the progressDialog to appear always on the top layer?

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the code i am using to get this progressDialog:

```
try {
            IRunnableWithProgress process = new IRunnableWithProgress() {


                @Override
                public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
                        InterruptedException {
                        monitor.beginTask(taskName, steps);

                        result = execution(monitor);
                        monitor.done();
                }


            };
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setActive();
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService().busyCursorWhile(process);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You have no control over the dialog displayed by this. How are you running this when a property page dialog is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the dialog shown by the progress service.

If you want to show progress from a preference page (or some other dialog) use `ProgressMonitorDialog` rather than the progress service. This also accepts an `IRunnableWithProgress`:

```
ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(getShell()) {
    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
      super.configureShell(shell);
      shell.setText("Dialog title");
    }
};

try {
   dialog.run(true, true, progress);
}   
... catches ...
```

Comment: Works like a charme! Thanks Sir.